# Django | Advice for making models that are related with out model inheritances for a blog post type

Tags: django, models

I have been reading about model inheritances in django and have found that many are not for it, though I'm not 100% sure why.

So I have a question for all of you who think model inheritances is bad.

I have a case were I have a blog with many sub types of a post model.

for an example lets say post1 is a common post type and post2 is a audio post type. Both post types have a title and date and other common fields, but also have unique fields used just for for their respective use.

First Q: what is the best way to make the models for both Post1 and Post2?
Second Q: what is the best way to get a list with all post types in order of date for showing in the blog roll?

--:Edit:-- I don't want this to be a debate if model / db inheritances is good or bad, I just want to find a contrast to what I think can be done. I have seen the debate many times over in the oop world about inheritance vs composition design, I know that I could use inheritance in django but I want to learn how to do it the as a composition design pattern.

Here is a good read for this issue that outlines some of the problems I have found with db inheritance http://ankhos.com/2010/01/15/django-polymorphism-mixins-vs-inheritance-models/

Comment: Who is against model inheritance? What is their problem with it?

Comment: James Bennett for Django In Depth say that "He doesn't think db level inheritances is a good idea" as seen in http://youtube.com/embed/t_ziKY1ayCo at 1:29:20

Comment: So, one guy has a problem with it.

Comment: That one guy so happens to be a release manager for Django. I think he is worth listening to. Unfortunately he didn't go into detail supporting his statement. Regardless I'm not going to debate with you if its good or bad, I just asked if there is another way and if so what is it. If you don't think there is another way just so.

Comment: Do the extra fields need to be filtered or searched?

Comment: @okm I have not got that far as of yet, but I could see how I may want to. If I ever find that to be a problem I'm sure there is work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1Q: You need something like polymorphism to save your two types of posts in one blog. I really liked this approach:

[Manager-based polymorphic model inheritance](https://gist.github.com/608687)

2Q: It's good explained in the doc string.

EDIT: read your edit. It seems like you want to try an other approach.

Comment: Very cool thanks. I will read this and tell you what I think. About the whole inheritance vs composition, it would nice to see a contrast to the inheritance but I also want to use what works best and if this code can address the current issues with db inheritance then great :)

Comment: So how is this on performance. I have played with the ContentType work around for db inheritance and found I hit the db more then I would like.